# Do I require a washer/spacer/shim between a hub's cone nut and lock nut?

Tags: hub, axle

When replacing the cones for a front hub with new ones, is it okay to tighten the lock nut directly against the cone nut?  Or must I use some kind of spacer / washer / shim in order for some other reason than spacing?

The reason I ask is that I am replacing the cones on a front hub that was correctly spaced at 100mm.  The old setup has

```
Lock nut - Washer - Cone nut - Hub/Cups - Cone nut - Washer - Lock nut
```

The replacement cones I got match in the old ones in all ways except that they are slightly wider (i.e. take more space of the axle).  So, instead of getting two more cones ($20 more dollars!), I figured I could just leave out the old washers and leave the setup like this, which would be spaced about 100mm:

```
Lock nut -      New Cone nut - Hub/Cups - New Cone nut      - Lock nut
```

So, would this be alright?  Does the original washer play any other role than just making the spacing correct?

Comment: Having washers between the two nuts is probably more the exception than the rule.

Comment: Freewheel axles often needed a long spacer between the cone and the locknut.  However its unusual on freewheel axles.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've just rebuilt a totally stock Shimano wheel set and it had locknuts touching cones all over the place. Go for it.

Comment: Can I assume you mean that the stock wheel had no washers before the rebuild?

Comment: That is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 8):

Some axles [Maillard, Campag etc.] have a keyway along the threaded portions. An internal-tabbed washer slides on , between the cone and the locknut, to prevent locknut rotation also spinning the cone itself.  It's a good system; and in that case, the tabbed washer should be used.  With Shimano hubs, where the keyway-&-tab system has been abandoned, the washer serves no purpose, except as a space adjuster along the axle. So can be left in or out, as suits you.

Comment: Welcome to bikes.SE! Thanks for a great first answer and hope to see you around more.